# GPO applied to OU does not appear to apply all settings

Tags: azure-active-directory, windows-server-2012-r2, group-policy

We have a couple service accounts added to our Default Domain Policy that grant them log on as a service rights. We installed the Azure AD Sync tool on a different server which seems to have created it's own local account for the tool. After rebooting that box during the last round of updates, we noticed the Azure AD Sync service failed to start due to a "logon issue".

Looking at the local security policy, it looks like the allow log on as a service option is showing only the service accounts applied at the default domain policy level. I assume this is what's causing the issue so I created a new policy and linked it to the OU where the server with the AD Sync tool lives.

Ran a gpupdate /force on that server, ran a gpresult /r to confirm it picked up the new GPO. Went into the GPO console on a DC and ran a GPO result query of the server with the AD sync tool and confirmed the new GPO wins and it even shows the new accounts I want.

Went back to the server with the tool and checked the local security policy and it does not show the local service account that i added to the new GPO and starting the service still fails. Anyone every experience this?

Answer (score 0):

okay...this is stupid, but the fix was to reboot the windows server....